# Does lightbox supports html5 or suggest any alternatives

Tags: jquery, html, css, image-gallery

I am creating a static website using html5 and css3 where I wanted to add image gallery (not image slider) with video support. I used a “prettyPhoto” which is a jquery image gallery plugin inside jquery ui tab. However it didn't worked. I also tried changing 'rel' to 'class' inside prettyPhoto js and css source code but it still didn't worked. so I am looking for alternatives?

```
html source code:
<!--Tabbed Image Gallery-->
            <div id="portfolio-list">
                    <div id="tabs" class="tabs-bottom">

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Graphic design</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Web design</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Flash</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tabs-3">3d</a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <div id="tabs-1">
                         <ul>
                            <li><a href="img/Colorful (1).jpg" class=”prettyPhoto”><img src="img/Colorful (1).jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="sample1"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                        </ul>

                        </div>
                        <div id="tabs-2">

                        </div>
                        <div id="tabs-3">

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with HTML5/CSS3?

Comment: If you are doing an html5/css3 solution there are some css3 only lightbox solutions. Here are a few http://www.net-kit.com/10-css3-lightbox-alternatives/

Comment: http://forums.no-margin-for-errors.com/discussion/1700/relprettyphoto-is-invalid-keyword-for-rel-attribute-for-html5/p1